# using mbox to keep an equation from splitting while also maintaining right justification

Tags: equations, justification

I have an equation which I would like to not split. I have used mbox to prevent it from splitting however doing so causes the text to no longer be right justified. Is it possible to do both and if so, how?

Here is the latex code (please ignore the mathematical content, I am just asking about the formatting):

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}

N are $Z$ and $Z-\{0\}$ respectively. For each i, both M and N interpret
$R_i$ as \mbox{$\{(x,-x): x \in Z \land 0<|x|\leq i\}$}. Consider the
finite sublanguage \mbox{$L_{i_0}=\{R_i:i\leq i_0\}\subseteq L$}. To see
that $M|L_{i_0}\cong N|L_{i_0}$, consider the bijection
$\phi:M\rightarrow N$ defined.

\end{document}
```

and here is a picture of the pdf it generates

[image]

Notice the equation `L_{i_0}=\{R_i:i\leq i_0\}\subseteq L` is extending into the right margin

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. For me, it is more readable having long equations on their own line: there is less cognitive load that way, in terms of mentally separating text from math. Do you have limited space?

Comment: Display mode looks presentable: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}
N are $Z$ and $Z-\{0\}$ respectively. For each i, both M and N interpret
$R_i$ as \[\{(x,-x): x \in Z \land 0<|x|\leq i\}.\] Consider the
finite sublanguage \[L_{i_0}=\{R_i:i\leq i_0\}\subseteq L.\] To see
that $M|L_{i_0}\cong N|L_{i_0}$, consider the bijection
$\phi:M\rightarrow N$ defined.
\end{document}`

Comment: Math symbols should always be in math mode: `For each~$i$, both $M$ and $N$ interpret...` The `~` avoids “i“ going to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cicada's comment is the "right" answer, in my opinion. Whitespace is your friend, and using it liberally dramatically improves readability. I would write

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent %we are imagining there is more paragraph above this line.
$N$ are $Z$ and $Z-\{0\}$ respectively. For each $i$, both $M$ and $N$ interpret $R_i$ as 
\[\{(x,-x): x \in Z \land 0<|x|\leq i\}.\] 
Consider the finite sublanguage 
\[L_{i_0}=\{R_i:i\leq i_0\}\subseteq L.\] 
To see that $M|L_{i_0}\cong N|L_{i_0}$, consider the bijection $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ defined.

\end{document}
```

Which renders as

[image: render of above code]

If you're positive you want inline text (this happens to me sometimes), I just use brackets around the entire math expression:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent %we are imagining there is more paragraph above this line.
$N$ are $Z$ and $Z-\{0\}$ respectively. 
For each $i$, both $M$ and $N$ interpret $R_i$ as $\{(x,-x): x \in Z \land 0<|x|\leq i\}$. 
Consider the finite sublanguage ${L_{i_0}=\{R_i:i\leq i_0\}\subseteq L}$. 
To see that $M|L_{i_0}\cong N|L_{i_0}$, consider the bijection $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ defined.

\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image: render of above code]

Comment: To be on the picky side, it should be `$.` and not `.$`

Comment: I haven’t noticed any difference in rendering, I’m in the habit of writing `.$` since I also need to write `./]` at the end of display math with a period. What’s the advantage of `$.`?

Comment: The period doesn't belong in an inline formula. No big difference if you use `\frenchspacing`, quite big otherwise.

Comment: Oh interesting! I just learned something. I’ll edit.